# Upgrading from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS failing

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, server, upgrade, lts

I'm getting the message:

> Your HWE is supported until April 2017" and "New Release 14.04.1 LTS
>   available.

However when trying to upgrade, I receive "no new release found".

I've attempted to:

- run `sudo do-release upgrade` and with "d" parameter
- run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
- run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- checked HWE kernel and updated to Trusty version and also set back to prior generic version (based on prior bug post)
- ensured update manager (core) is installed

Server Now Running:

```
- 12.04.05 LTS (Precise)
- 3.13.0-115-generic X86_64
```

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file contains:
 [DEFAULT]
 Prompt=lts

I even tried changing to "normal" and running.

Comment: I was also wondering if anyone has tried updating server via .ISO (CD/DVD) route? such as in this thread;
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

phew; if you go to 14.04.1 you do get support for 2 more years;

like you, we were on 12.04 but made the big leap to 16.04 recently; we did a fresh install;

if you look at the idea of creating a home partition; then your own files are separate; and updating the system files of a distro becomes much simpler;

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

only 14.04.1 is supported now as you know: as the rest are long gone

---

but back to what you did: the d option is said to refer to development issue; so that classification no longer applies to the 14 series;

the `do-release-upgrade -c` is said to allow you to *check* what you might get

---

*it is also suggested you can find it through upgrade manager*

```
Or (for the GUI way - this program is also known as the Software Updater and can be searched and found in the GUI under that name):
```

update-manager

For this though once you are completely up-to-date with all the latest updates it will show you an Upgrade... button which will allow you to upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: I attempted with the -c and no classification with the same result "no new release found". I'm running from terminal - attempted locally at console.

Comment: (1/4) Linux 3.13.0-116-generic #163~precise1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
 (2/4) Distributor Id: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS Release: 12.04 Codename: Precise
 (3/4) Ran apt-get dist-upgrade without problems (also ran apt-get upgrade without problems)
 (4/4) Updated the kernel to 3.13.0-116 (I've tried to upgrade with both 115 and 116 Trusty kernels)

Comment: I've also run:

sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a

to check for any broken dependencies. Everything seems fine. I have read where the sources.list file can be manually edited to Trusty DEB pointers, but this may cause system issues, any further ideas?

Comment: when you ask for further ideas; unfortunately mine are around maybe thinking of a new, small partition to put 16.04 on; and access personal files on old partition; or copying personal data to a usb drive; and starting with a new install;sorry

Comment: Thanks PDC but since it's a server with apps, that seems like a laborious process in what should be a simple 3-4 step upgrade. It's gotta be something I'm just overlooking (third-party video driver interference perhaps), I'm still researching and thanks again for the input!

Comment: Ah! I wonder if posting on the "install&upgrades" section of the main ubuntu forums might help? .. not all of the gurus there may have migrated to here and some long-established expertise there;